# How to make JAXB use custom namespace prefixes

Tags: xml, gradle, xsd, jaxb, xjc

When marshalling an object to XML with JAXB, it automatically generates namespace prefixes like `ns2:`. The system I have to communicate with unfortunately doesn't work with these default prefixes (despite the fact that the XML is perfectly valid), so I want to create a mapping of the prefixes there should be for all different namespaces. The XSD is also used for other projects, so I would prefer not to have to make any changes in it.

I found 2 solutions in other answers and on other websites:

1. Use a namespace prefix mapper class. Sounds perfect, but unfortunately this is no longer an option, as the relevant property no longer exists on the marshaller (using `jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:4.0.0`).
2. Add `XmlNs` annotations in `package-info.java`. This seems like the only option that's left (besides search/replace in the XML file after marshalling), but this file is generated: all Java classes are generated from the XSD with an XJC task using Gradle. Manual additions of such annotations to the package-info files would be overwritten by the next run of a generate task.

My questions: is there a way to provide JAXB with my own prefix mapping? Or is there a way to have XJC generate those XmlNs annotations automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HiSrc HyperJAXB Annox](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb-annox#readme) provides an XJC plugin that can add Java annotations to your generated `package-info.java`. You can add an annotation to specify a custom `xmlns`. To use it, add the jar (below) to your XJC classpath and add this argument to your XJC invocation, `-Xannotate`.

**XJC Add-On Jar**

```
<groupId>org.patrodyne.jvnet</groupId>
<artifactId>hisrc-hyperjaxb-annox-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.1.0</version>
```

Configure the `annox` extension in your bindings file at any one `complexType`, like this ...

**Bindings Example**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxb:bindings jaxb:version="3.0"
    xmlns:jaxb="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:annox="http://jvnet.org/basicjaxb/xjc/annox"
    jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="annox"
>
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="PurchaseOrder.xsd" node="/xsd:schema" >
        <jaxb:bindings node="xsd:element[@name='purchaseOrder']/xsd:complexType">
            ...
            <annox:annotatePackage>
                @jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
                    xmlns = {
                        @jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix = "po", namespaceURI = "http://example.org/po")
                    })
            </annox:annotatePackage>
            ...
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Each time you run your XJC action in your build, the `package-info.java` class should include your defined `XmlNs` prefix.

*Disclaimer:* I am the maintainer of the forked HiSrc projects.

BTW, in the [Eclipse JAXB implementation](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jaxb-ri/3.0.0/docs/ch05.html#prefixmapper), the `NamespacePrefixMapper` and its property can be found at:

```
Mapper: org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.marshaller.NamespacePrefixMapper
Used By: org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl
Property: org.glassfish.jaxb.namespacePrefixMapper
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the elaborate reply! I decided to opt for the second solution, using the Eclipse implementation, as then I don't have to change the binding file (it's shared between multiple projects, just like the XSD files). With the Eclipse implementation the `NamespacePrefixMapper` property indeed works perfectly!

Comment: I tried using the mentioned approach but I get the error `property "org.glassfish.jaxb.namespacePrefixMapper" is not supported`, can you please once check and provide some response: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78122874/7584240

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question from [BATMAN_2008](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7584240/batman-2008) ...

This [download (zip)](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/releases/download/2.2.0/hisrc-higherjaxb-sample-workday-2.2.0-mvn-src.zip) contains a stand-alone Maven project to unmarshal the given XML [workday-01.xml](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/workday/src/test/samples/workday-01.xml) file into JAXB objects and then marshal the objects back into XML.

> This demo has been enhanced to demonstrate how to configure a *custom prefix* for an XML namespace using two alternative approaches:
>
> 1. `package-info.java` OR
> 2. `org.glassfish.jaxb.namespacePrefixMapper`.

After unzipping it to your local folder, you can run the test using:

```
mvn -Ptest clean test
```

The output shows two alternative custom XML namespace prefixes, `"wd:"` and `"workday:"`.

**DEBUG Workday Root 1 (wd):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvo">
    <wd:Put_Absence_Input_Request wd:version="v39.2">
        <wd:Absence_Input_Data>
            <wd:Batch_ID>Import 15022023</wd:Batch_ID>
            <wd:Worker_Reference>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Employee_ID">1741538</wd:ID>
            </wd:Worker_Reference>
            <wd:Absence_Component_Reference>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Accrual_Code">FRA_Shadow_Accrual_for_Time_Offs_Impacting_Accrual_of_Paid_Annual_Leave_CP</wd:ID>
            </wd:Absence_Component_Reference>
            <wd:Start_Date>2023-01-01</wd:Start_Date>
            <wd:End_Date>2023-01-31</wd:End_Date>
            <wd:Reference_Date>2023-01-15</wd:Reference_Date>
            <wd:Hours>2.08</wd:Hours>
            <wd:Adjustment>false</wd:Adjustment>
        </wd:Absence_Input_Data>
    </wd:Put_Absence_Input_Request>
</root>
```

The first output marshals the XML with a `"wd:"` prefix. This prefix is configured in the [root.xjb](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/workday/src/main/resources/root.xjb) binding file to customize the JAXB generated classes. The result is a custom `package-info` class with a declared `"wd:` prefix. This approach declares the prefix at *build* time.

**`package-info.java`**

```
@jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "urn:com.workday/bsvo", elementFormDefault = jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED, xmlns = {
    @jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix = "wd", namespaceURI = "urn:com.workday/bsvo")
})
package com.workday.bsvo;
```

**DEBUG Workday Root 2 (workday):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root xmlns:workday="urn:com.workday/bsvo">
    <workday:Put_Absence_Input_Request workday:version="v39.2">
        <workday:Absence_Input_Data>
            <workday:Batch_ID>Import 15022023</workday:Batch_ID>
            <workday:Worker_Reference>
                <workday:ID workday:type="Employee_ID">1741538</workday:ID>
            </workday:Worker_Reference>
            <workday:Absence_Component_Reference>
                <workday:ID workday:type="Accrual_Code">FRA_Shadow_Accrual_for_Time_Offs_Impacting_Accrual_of_Paid_Annual_Leave_CP</workday:ID>
            </workday:Absence_Component_Reference>
            <workday:Start_Date>2023-01-01</workday:Start_Date>
            <workday:End_Date>2023-01-31</workday:End_Date>
            <workday:Reference_Date>2023-01-15</workday:Reference_Date>
            <workday:Hours>2.08</workday:Hours>
            <workday:Adjustment>false</workday:Adjustment>
        </workday:Absence_Input_Data>
    </workday:Put_Absence_Input_Request>
</root>
```

The second output marshals the XML with a `"workday:"` prefix. This prefix is configured in the [WorkdayTest](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/workday/src/test/java/com/workday/bsvo/WorkdayTest.java) class using a custom JAXB marshaller. This approach declares the prefix at *run* time and overrides the `package-info` configuration.

**`WorkdayTest.java`**

```
...
marshaller.setProperty("org.glassfish.jaxb.namespacePrefixMapper", NAMESPACE_PREFIX_MAPPER);
...
public static final NamespacePrefixMapper NAMESPACE_PREFIX_MAPPER = new NamespacePrefixMapper()
{
    @Override
    public String getPreferredPrefix(String namespaceUri, String suggestion, boolean requirePrefix)
    {
        return "workday";
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, the second example was exactly what I needed.