# How to use the custom namespaces from the JAXB RI? Error: "org.glassfish.jaxb.namespacePrefixMapper" is not supported

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb-ri

Previously I was using the Eclipselink Moxy `NAMESPACE_PREFIX_MAPPER` to provide the custom namespaces to my `JaxbContext` and `Marshaller` and everything was working as expected. But I want to move away from the Moxy and use JAXB RI so changed everything.

The only problem that I am facing is related to providing the `MarshallerProperties` and `JAXBContextProperties`. I changed them to use from glassfish as per the [answer mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76551823/7584240) and the [documentation](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jaxb-ri/3.0.0/docs/ch05.html#indent) but after the change I am facing error:

```
Exception in thread "main" jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBException: property "org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.marshaller.NamespacePrefixMapper" is not supported
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:126)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:58)
    at jakarta.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:324)
    at jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:392)
    at io.test.convert.MainXML.main(MainXML.java:27)
```

Following is the completed code I have:
`Child1.class`:

```
package io.test.convert;

import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;

@XmlRootElement(name = "Child1")
@XmlType(
        name = "Child1",
        propOrder = {
                "name",
                "age",
                "originalName"
        },
        factoryClass = ObjectFactory.class,
        factoryMethod = "createChild1")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Child1 extends Parent {
    private String originalName;
}
```

`Parent.class`:

```
package io.test.convert;

import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.io.Serializable;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlTransient
@Builder
public class Parent implements Serializable {
    @XmlTransient
    private String type;
    private String name;
    private String age;
}
```

`CustomNamespacePrefixMapper.class`:

```
package io.test.convert;

import org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.marshaller.NamespacePrefixMapper;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class CustomNamespacePrefixMapper extends NamespacePrefixMapper {
    public static final Map<String, String> NAMESPACE_MAP = Map.of(
            "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "xsi",
            "https://example1.com/", "example1",
            "https://example2.com/", "example2");

    private Map<String, String> namespaceMap;
    public CustomNamespacePrefixMapper(final Map<String, String> namespaceMap) {
        this.namespaceMap = namespaceMap;
    }
    public CustomNamespacePrefixMapper() {
        this(new HashMap<>(NAMESPACE_MAP));
    }
    @Override
    public String getPreferredPrefix(String namespaceUri, String suggestion, boolean requirePrefix) {
        return namespaceMap.getOrDefault(namespaceUri, suggestion);
    }
}
```

`MainXML.class`:

```
package io.test.convert;

import jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import jakarta.xml.bind.Marshaller;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainXML {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final Map<String, String> myNamespaces = new HashMap<>();
        myNamespaces.put("test", "https://test.com");
        myNamespaces.put("test2", "https://test2.com");

        final JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("io.test.convert", Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(),
                new HashMap<>() {
                    {
                        put(
                                "org.glassfish.jaxb.namespacePrefixMapper",
                                new CustomNamespacePrefixMapper());
                    }
                });
        //final JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("io.test.convert", Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());

        final Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.setProperty("org.glassfish.jaxb.namespacePrefixMapper", new CustomNamespacePrefixMapper());

        final Child1 child1 = new Child1();
        child1.setName("Batman");
        child1.setAge("30");
        child1.setType("Superhero");
        child1.setOriginalName("Bruce Wayne");

        marshaller.marshal(child1, System.out);
    }
}
```

Following is my `sampleXML.xml`:

```
<Child1>
    <type>ChildType</type>
    <name>Batman</name>
    <age>30</age>
    <originalName>Bruce</originalName>
</Child1>
```

`ObjectFactory.class`:

```
package io.test.convert;

import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRegistry;

@XmlRegistry
public final class ObjectFactory {
    private ObjectFactory() {}
    public static Child1 createChild1() {
        return new Child1();
    }
}
```

When I run I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBException: property "org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.marshaller.NamespacePrefixMapper" is not supported
```

How to provide the custom namespaces to the `JAXBContext/Marshaller` so it can be used during the marshalling of the Java objects to XML?

Following are my dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.30</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Did you try the `org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.marshaller.NamespacePrefixMapper` property ?

Comment: @LaurentSchoelens Thanks for the response, Yes I tried same error: `Exception in thread "main" jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBException: property "org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.marshaller.NamespacePrefixMapper" is not supported`

Comment: Could you then share which version of jaxb-ri you're using ?

Comment: @LaurentSchoelens I am using all the latest version which is `<version>4.0.1</version>`

Comment: Latest runtime is 4.0.4 for me. Api is 4.0.1

Comment: @LaurentSchoelens oh ok, I updated to latest version `4.0.4` but still getting the same issue: `property "org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.marshaller.NamespacePrefixMapper" is not supported`. I have added the code sample for the question, can you please check and provide some response on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

For jaxb-ri, the property should be `org.glassfish.jaxb.namespacePrefixMapper` and the value with it should be of type `org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.marshaller.NamespacePrefixMapper`

If not, you'll see the exception you've seen before (property not handled or must be of type ...)

Source [here](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxb-ri/blob/b4e7cfdf3e8dcc22dbf7423729c090ae369db21a/jaxb-ri/runtime/impl/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jaxb/runtime/v2/runtime/MarshallerImpl.java#L459)

**EDIT**

In addition to my previous first answer, you should pass the namespaceMapper property in JAXBContext creation.

See supported properties during JAXBContext phase in the following method : `org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.ContextFactory#createContext(java.lang.Class[], java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>)`

You should create your JAXBContext with your current commented line of code :

```java
final JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("io.test.convert", Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
```

If doing so and adding the `namespace` to `Child1` class as `@XmlRootElement(name = "Child1", namespace = "https://example1.com/")`, you'll get the following output :

```xml
<example1:Child1 xmlns:example1="https://example1.com/">
    <name>Batman</name>
    <age>30</age>
    <originalName>Bruce Wayne</originalName>
</example1:Child1>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. I have tried this and still getting the error `Exception in thread "main" jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBException: property "org.glassfish.jaxb.namespacePrefixMapper" is not supported`. Can you please suggest something?

Comment: I was trying different things that time i may have added it as `org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.marshaller.NamespacePrefixMapper;` instead of the `org.glassfish.jaxb.namespacePrefixMapper`. I have updated the question with correct code and still getting the error `Exception in thread "main" jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBException: property "org.glassfish.jaxb.namespacePrefixMapper" is not supported`

Comment: Edited answer as I've copy / paste all your code in own project to test what's going on

Comment: Thanks for the response but I do not wish to add the namespaces to my class. Because some of the namespaces are dynamic so I want to provide them just before the marshalling. Previously I was using the `moxy` where I could pass the `import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties` while creating the `JAXBContext` and `import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.MarshallerProperties;` during the marshalling `marshaller.setProperty(
                MarshallerProperties.NAMESPACE_PREFIX_MAPPER,
                myNamespaces);` this was working perfectly but I want to move away.

Comment: Not a problem, just saying that if namespace is well-defined, the `CustomNamespacePrefixMapper` does its job :)

Comment: Is there any other alternative approach to provide the namespaces before marshalling? Like `marshaller.setProperty("org.glassfish.jaxb.namespacePrefixMapper", myNamespaces);` because currently this is not working and namespaces are not used and getting error as well.

Comment: You can also use the same approach as the [namespace prefix plugin](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools/wiki/JAXB2-Namespace-Prefix-Plugin). You can define in `package-info.java` file (same as java-jaxb-classes) some annotation like `@XmlNs(namespaceURI = "https://example1.com/", prefix = "example1")`